# d3.js のパイチャートでラベルの重なりを逆順にしたい

Tags: javascript, d3.js

d3.js をつかって円グラフをかいてみたんですが
後半に少ないデータが固まるとラベルが重なってしまいます

その時に少しでも多いデータがはっきりわかるように
手前に表示したいんですがどうすればいいのでしょうか

```
const g = svg.selectAll(".arc")
    .data(pie(data))
    .enter()
    .append("g")
    .attr('z-index', d => 10 - d.index)
    .attr("class", "arc");
```

ここで z-index を指定しても g タグには聞かないみたいです

g.arc の追加順を逆にすればよさそうなのですが

```
    .enter()
    .append("g")
```

の間に get() とか reverse() とかをはさんでもメソッドがないといわれて
Selection というオブジェクトみたいで配列に変換したり
追加順を制御することもできません

```html
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.js"></script>
<script>
  const data = [
    {legend: '●94%', value: 94, color: '#fcc'},
    {legend: '●3%', value: 3, color: '#ecd'},
    {legend: '●2%', value: 2, color: '#dce'},
    {legend: '●1%', value: 1, color: '#ccf'},
  ];

  $('html').append('<svg></svg>');
  const svg = d3.select('svg');
  const pie = d3.pie().value(d => d.value);
  const arc = d3.arc().innerRadius(0);
  let isAnimated = false;

  const render = () => {
    const g = svg.selectAll(".arc")
    .data(pie(data))
    .enter()
    .append("g")
    .attr('z-index', d => 10 - d.index)
    .attr("class", "arc");

    g.append("path")
    .attr("fill", d => d.data.color )
    .attr("stroke", "white");

    g.append("text")
    .attr("stroke", "black")
    .attr("fill", "white")
    .attr("font-weight", "BOLD")
    .attr('text-anchor', 'middle')
    .text((d) => d.data.legend);
  };


  const update = () => {
    const size = 200;
    arc.outerRadius(size / 2);

    svg
      .attr("width", size)
      .attr("height", size);

    const g = svg.selectAll(".arc")
    .attr("transform", `translate(${size / 2}, ${size / 2})`);

    g.selectAll("text").attr("transform", d => `translate(${arc.centroid(d)})`);

  }

  const animate = () => {
    const g = svg.selectAll(".arc");
    const length = data.length;
    let i = 0;

    g.selectAll("path")
    .transition()
    .attrTween("d", (b) => {
      const interpolate = d3.interpolate(
        {startAngle: 0, endAngle: 0, opacity: 0}, b
      );
      return (t) => {
        if(t >= 1) {
          i++;
          isAnimated = i === length;
        }
        return arc(interpolate(t));
      };
    });
    };

  render();
  update();
  animate();
</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

例えば `data` の要素の順序を `value` をキーにして逆順にしてみると、

```js
data.sort((a, b) => {return a.value - b.value});
```

以下の様に表示されます。

[image: reverse order]

表示されている SVG 画像の中身(source code)を確認してみると、

```xml
                   :
<g class="arc" transform="translate(100, 100)">
<path fill="#ecd" ...></path>
<text stroke="black" fill="white" ...>●3%</text>
</g>
                   :
```

となっていて、描画の順序としては最初(`data[0]`)のアークシェイプとそのラベル、次に `data[1]` のアークシェイプとそのラベル、となります。これは以下の様に、ラベルを `arc` の子ノードとして追加しているためです。

```js
  const g = svg.selectAll(".arc")
          :

  g.append("path")
          :

  g.append("text")
          :
```

ではどうするのかと言えば、ラベルを `arc` の子ノードから外して `svg` に追加します。その上で、最後にまとめて描画します。

```html
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.js"></script>
<script>
  const data = [
    {legend: '●94%', value: 94, color: '#fcc'},
    {legend: '●3%', value: 3, color: '#ecd'},
    {legend: '●2%', value: 2, color: '#dce'},
    {legend: '●1%', value: 1, color: '#ccf'},
  ];

  data.sort((a, b) => {return a.value - b.value});

  $('html').append('<svg></svg>');
  const svg = d3.select('svg');
  const pie = d3.pie().value(d => d.value);
  const arc = d3.arc().innerRadius(0);
  let isAnimated = false;

  const render = () => {
    const g = svg.selectAll(".arc")
    .data(pie(data))
    .enter()
    .append("g")
    .attr('z-index', d => 10 - d.index)
    .attr("class", "arc");

    g.append("path")
    .attr("fill", d => d.data.color )
    .attr("stroke", "white");

    svg.selectAll("text")
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append("text")
    .attr("stroke", "black")
    .attr("fill", "white")
    .attr("font-weight", "BOLD")
    .attr('text-anchor', 'middle')
    .text(d => d.legend);

  };


  const update = () => {
    const size = 200;
    arc.outerRadius(size / 2);

    svg
      .attr("width", size)
      .attr("height", size);

    const g = svg.selectAll(".arc")
    .attr("transform", `translate(${size / 2}, ${size / 2})`);

    svg.selectAll("text")
    .attr("transform", (_, i) =>
          `translate(${
            arc.centroid(g.data()[i]).map(v => v + size/2)
          })`);

  };

  const animate = () => {
    const g = svg.selectAll(".arc");
    const length = data.length;
    let i = 0;

    g.selectAll("path")
    .transition()
    .attrTween("d", (b) => {
      const interpolate = d3.interpolate(
        {startAngle: 0, endAngle: 0, opacity: 0}, b
      );
      return (t) => {
        if(t >= 1) {
          i++;
          isAnimated = i === length;
        }
        return arc(interpolate(t));
      };
    });
    };

  render();
  update();
  animate();
</script>
</html>
```

以降は余録的なものですが、もう少しラベルを見やすくしてみます(表示位置を微調整しています)。

```html
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.js"></script>
<script>
  const data = [
    {legend: '●94%', value: 94, color: '#fcc'},
    {legend: '●3%', value: 3, color: '#ecd'},
    {legend: '●2%', value: 2, color: '#dce'},
    {legend: '●1%', value: 1, color: '#ccf'},
  ];

  $('html').append('<svg></svg>');
  const svg = d3.select('svg');
  const pie = d3.pie().value(d => d.value);
  const arc = d3.arc().innerRadius(0);
  let isAnimated = false;

  const render = () => {
    const g = svg.selectAll(".arc")
    .data(pie(data))
    .enter()
    .append("g")
    .attr('z-index', d => 10 - d.index)
    .attr("class", "arc");

    g.append("path")
    .attr("fill", d => d.data.color )
    .attr("stroke", "white");

    svg.selectAll("text")
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append("text")
    .attr("stroke", "black")
    .attr("fill", "white")
    .attr("font-weight", "BOLD")
    .attr('text-anchor', 'middle')
    .text(d => d.legend);

  };


  const update = () => {
    const size = 200;
    arc.outerRadius(size / 2);

    svg
      .attr("width", size)
      .attr("height", size);

    const g = svg.selectAll(".arc")
    .attr("transform", `translate(${size / 2}, ${size / 2})`);

    svg.selectAll("text")
    .attr("transform", (_, i) =>
      `translate(${
        arc.centroid(g.data()[i])
           .map((v, j) => {
             return size/2 + v + (
               (g.data()[i].data.value<10) ?
                 (j?((i-1)*30-20):(i*2+5)) : 0)
           })
      })`)

  };

  const animate = () => {
    const g = svg.selectAll(".arc");
    const length = data.length;
    let i = 0;

    g.selectAll("path")
    .transition()
    .attrTween("d", (b) => {
      const interpolate = d3.interpolate(
        {startAngle: 0, endAngle: 0, opacity: 0}, b
      );
      return (t) => {
        if(t >= 1) {
          i++;
          isAnimated = i === length;
        }
        return arc(interpolate(t));
      };
    });
    };

  render();
  update();
  animate();
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: 追加データを逆にしても円グラフは多い順に作ってくれるのですね。arc の下でなくても g.data() で角度情報にアクセスできるのがとても参考になりました。